# Rainer Schuler's algorithm of CNF SAT problem

Tags: probability-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability

I'm reading through [this publication](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/18af/3a33829c2d1089daf7e0055dd0b8fb110517.pdf) trying to understand the algorithm and what exactly did Schuler achieve compared to Cook's theorem.

Can someone please explain me how this algorithm works in simple words or even refer me to a relevant article?

From the abstract of the paper "An algorithm for the satisfiability problem of formulas in conjunctive normal form":

> We consider the satisfiability problem on Boolean formulas in conjunctive normal form. We show
>   that a satisfying assignment of a formula can be found in polynomial time with a success probability
>   of $2^{−n(1−1/(1+\log m))}$, where $n$ and $m$ are the number of variables and the number of clauses of the
>   formula, respectively. If the number of clauses of the formulas is bounded by $n^c$ for some constant $c$,
>   this gives an expected run time of $O(p(n) \cdot 2^{n(1−1/(1+c \log n))})$ for a polynomial $p$.